Why did I use `TParallel.&For` in Delphi, but the performance was not improved at all, but was slower than running a thread?
I'm currently learning parallel programming in Delphi. When I tried to use TParallel.&For to optimize a for loop, I found that the result was not what I wanted. The result was even worse than before the optimization. I don't know if it was a problem with the way I used it or some other problem.
The following function is where I mainly use TParallel.&For. As you can see, what this function does is actually verify the Goldbach conjecture, the range of numbers is all even numbers between [6, MaxInt].

APrimes, this is the prime number table I have built in advance using the Euler sieve method, which contains all the prime numbers between [2, MaxInt];
IsPrime, this indicates whether all numbers in the range [2, MaxInt] are prime numbers. If IsPrime[Number] = True, then the Number is a prime number;
The above two variables have been created, and I can guarantee the accuracy of both.

procedure GoldBachCheckParallel(APrimes: TArray<Int64>; IsPrime: TArray<Boolean>);
begin
  TParallel.&For(6, MaxInt - 1, procedure(ANumber: Int64)
  var
    Index: Int64;
  begin
    if ANumber mod 2 <> 0 then
      Exit;
    Index := 0;
    for Index in APrimes do
    begin
      if IsPrime[Index] and IsPrime[ANumber - Index] then
        Break;
      if Index * Index > ANumber then
        Break;
    end;
  end);
end;

The full code is as follows：
unit Solution2;

interface

uses
  Classes, System.SysUtils;

procedure MainTest;

implementation

uses
  Math, System.Threading, CodeSiteLogging,
  Algorithm, MyUtils;

procedure GoldBachCheckParallel(APrimes: TArray<Int64>; IsPrime: TArray<Boolean>);
begin
  TParallel.&For(6, MaxInt - 1, procedure(ANumber: Int64)
  var
    Index: Int64;
  begin
    if ANumber mod 2 <> 0 then
      Exit;
    Index := 0;
    for Index in APrimes do
    begin
      if IsPrime[Index] and IsPrime[ANumber - Index] then
        Break;
      if Index * Index > ANumber then
        Break;
    end;
  end);
end;

procedure EulerAlgori(AMax: Int64; var APrimes: TArray<Int64>; var IsPrime: TArray<Boolean>);
var
  P, I: Int64;
  PrimeCount: Int64;
begin
  SetLength(IsPrime, AMax + 1);
  FillChar(IsPrime[0], Length(IsPrime) * SizeOf(Boolean), 1);
  SetLength(APrimes, 0);
  for I := 2 to AMax do
  begin
    if IsPrime[I] then
    begin
      PrimeCount := Length(APrimes);
      SetLength(APrimes, PrimeCount + 1);
      APrimes[PrimeCount] := I;
    end;
    for P := 0 to High(APrimes) do
    begin
      if (I * APrimes[P] > AMax) then
        Break;
      IsPrime[I * APrimes[P]] := False;
      if (I mod APrimes[P] = 0) then
        Break;
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure MainTest;
var
  LBeginTime, LEndTime: Int64;
  APrimes: TArray<Int64>;
  IsPrime: TArray<Boolean>;
begin
  LBeginTime := GetMicrosecondTime;
  CodeSite.Send('Start generating prime number table(s):', LBeginTime);
  EulerAlgori(MaxInt, APrimes, IsPrime);
  LEndTime := GetMicrosecondTime;
  CodeSite.Send('End of generating prime number table(s):', LEndTime);
  CodeSite.Send('Generating the prime number table costs(s):', LEndTime - LBeginTime);
  CodeSite.Send('The number of prime numbers generated:', Length(APrimes));
  LBeginTime := GetMicrosecondTime;
  CodeSite.Send('Begins to verify Goldbach conjecture(s):', LBeginTime);
  GoldBachCheckParallel(APrimes, IsPrime);
  LEndTime := GetMicrosecondTime;
  CodeSite.Send('End of verification of Goldbach conjecture(s):', LEndTime);
  CodeSite.Send('Verifying the Goldbach conjecture costs(s)', LEndTime - LBeginTime);
end;

end.

The result of running the above code is shown in the figure. Verifying the Goldbach conjecture costs 102s.
I wrote a single-threaded version before, and the running time was about 68 seconds.

I am very confused about this. I feel that this TParallel.&For does not help me much, but instead slows down the running speed. What did I do wrong?

How is the iteration space divided over the threads? How many threads are you using vs how many cores you have?

@VictorEijkhout There is a default thread pool at work, the minimum number of threads in the thread pool is 5 and the maximum number of threads is set to 40. And I have 20 cores. As for the amount of tasks assigned to each thread, this is related to the design of TParallel.for. The official website describes it this way: 'Iterates through a sequence of integral index values calling an event handler for each iteration such that any of these calls may be handled in a parallel thread.'

This is the official website: https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Alexandria/en/System.Threading.TParallel.For.
